# Column type for storing image links

Tags: sql, postgresql

bit of a newbie here, for my application I'm using postgres and I have a users table which has a column user_pictures. What column type should I store it as? json, jsonb, array, or something else? The list of images can be updated.

edit: I forgot to mention they are links, `'imgur.com/.....'`

Comment: Use the Binary Large Object (or `blob`) data type when you're storing binary data such as images, videos, etc. The name might vary a bit between systems but usually, the names used are `binary`, `bit` and `bit varying`.

Comment: I forgot to mention they are links, "imgur.com/....."

Comment: And there can be multiple images per user?

Comment: yeah so each row for the column user_pictures can have 0-5 links

Comment: If you're storing urls, not images, use an appropriately sized varchar.

Comment: You don't want to store it in 1 column. You want a table that holds a foreign key to your user and store 1 URL in 1 row.

Comment: A link is simply a string, so use `text`